# Keras LSTM docs don't say what the input shape should be?

Tags: keras, lstm

I'm feeding data into a **Keras LSTM** with the functional **API**.

Keras is telling me

```
expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

But the docs don't say what the three dimensions should be.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the entire model?check the number of output classes

Comment: The three dimensions should be `samples, timesteps, features`